# Zend Debugger - Wamp2.2 + Eclipse PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, zend-framework, wamp

I am trying to get zend debugger woking with eclipse so that I can trigger breakpoints in my code.

I have installed wamp 2.2 (uses PHP 5.3.10 - thread safe)

I have installed the eclipse 'all in one' package from zend.

I have updated my php.ini to include

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/zend_ext/ZendDebugger.dll"

[Zend]
zend_debugger.allow_hosts="127.0.0.1"
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
```

When I launch my php.exe it shows

```
Cannot load Zend Debugger - it was build with configuration API220090626,NTS,VC9, whereas running engine is API2200090626,TS,VC9
```

I have read that ZendDebugger only works as non thread safe so I cannot just download a ts version. I cannot find a download link for php 5.3.10 (http://windows.php.net/download/)

However, when I try to replace my copy of php with 5.3.13 (nts) my sqlsrv extension is not compatible and I get the error

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/ext/php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

If I change my php.ini to not load the sqlsrv extension I still get the error

```
Failed loading c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/zend_ext/ZendDebugger.dll
```

Does anyone know how I can get debugging to work with Zend Framework, Eclipse, wamp and sqlserv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot load Zend Debugger - it was build with configuration API220090626,**NTS**,VC9, whereas running engine is API2200090626,TS,VC9

NTS means Not-Thread-Safe, and hence you must use a NTS build of PHP... Which is how you run PHP as a FCGI process (vs. Apache Thread via mod_php).

Zend does not usually provide or support TS builds of anything anylonger (since after PHP 5.2), and it looks like your setup is meant for a TS build...

You could try two things:

Use a WAMP that ships with PHP as FCGI (NTS) option (I know the latest version of [Wamp-Developer](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) does, but it's commercial, maybe see if [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or another [Wamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs) does?)

Or instead of ZendDebugger, try using XDebug. It comes both as TS and NTS builds. And I'm sure you can use Eclipse with it.